# raise IOError('File not found: %s' % basename)

Tags: python, xml, python-3.6, odoo, odoo-12

i'm working on odoo 12 (python 3.6) and i'm trying to inherit from the product.template and add a new field after the standard price , but i had this error:

```
**Odoo Server Error 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 656, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 314, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 698, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 346, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 97, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 339, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 941, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 519, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 966, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 954, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 759, in call_kw
    return _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 746, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-61>", line 2, in button_immediate_install
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 74, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 445, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_install)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 561, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 421, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 313, in load_marked_modules
    perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 222, in load_module_graph
    load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package, report=report)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 68, in load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 796, in convert_file
    with file_open(pathname, 'rb') as fp:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\misc.py", line 199, in file_open
    return _fileopen(name, mode=mode, basedir=rtp, pathinfo=pathinfo, basename=basename)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\misc.py", line 257, in _fileopen
    raise IOError('File not found: %s' % basename)
OSError: File not found: tryinherit\tryinherit_views.xml**
```

this my tryinherit.py file

```
from odoo import models, fields, api


class Tryinherit(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'
    ShippingCost = fields.Float(string="Shipping Cost")
```

and this is my tryinherit_views.xml file

```
<odoo>
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_form_tryinherit">
      <field name="name">Product</field>
      <field name="model">product.template</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_form_view"/>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
          <xpath expr="//field[@name='standard_price']" position="after">
              <group>
              <field name="ShippingCost"/>
              </group>
          </xpath>
      </field>
    </record>
```

**Help me please**

Comment: Have put `tryinherit_views.xml` file in `manifest.py` properly?

Comment: Yes  `'data': [
        # 'security/ir.model.access.csv',
        'tryinherit_views.xml',
        # 'views/templates.xml',
    ],  ` @PruthviBarot

Comment: it should be `'views/tryinherit_views.xml'`

Comment: @PruthviBarot Thank you the problem is solved